# My site does not load on new Safari version 15

Tags: safari

My ruby on rails website does not load on safari 15. It works fine on older versions as well as other browsers. The below is what I see in Safari 15[image]

There is nothing in the console logs or any indication of what the "problem" is. Interestingly this is also an issue for my site if I run it locally on localhost:3000 which leads me to think it's an issue with something in my sites code.

If I disable Javascript the site will then load, what in my Javascript could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this ended up being an issue with Three.js, I needed to upgrade it's version then the site worked in safari. If you're not using Three.js, then I'd recommend checking the other JavaScript packages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar problem with my matured React app. Some users of my web application are using Safari 15 and they report that some fragments of the application are not loaded.
I also got screenshots from them. There is nothing indicated in the console.
But interesstingly all the HTML canvas elements are not rendered. Even the small ones.

Some examples:

Leaflet map in canvas (map tiles somehow not rendered):

[image: A Leaflet map]

A chart in a canvas (chart stays blank):

[image: A chart rendered in Canvas]

I mean it is working in every other browser since years and also Safari 14 and Safari on iOs.

Must be something Safari 15 realted.